# postgresql dump - unable to use it to create a new database on a new server

Tags: postgresql

I've run the following command on an existing database server:

```
 pg_dump -C -U testuser testdb -h 127.0.0.1 -F t> testdbdump
```

Now I'm trying to create this testdb on a new server. 
I tried to run the following command on the new server:

```
 pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 testdbdump
```

I've created the testuser role on the new database server.  And then I also tried the following:

```
pg_restore -i -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres "testdbdump"

psql template1 postgres -f testdbdump
```

It did start to do some stuff, but I get a bunch of errors including:

```
psql:testdbdump:1720: invalid command \N
psql:testdbdump:1721: invalid command \N
psql:testdbdump:1808: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 1: user=phone
        ^
```

Did I create the dump file incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried connecting as postgres to template1?

Comment: I've tried connecting as postgres... but i don't know what you mean by template1

Comment: template1 is the default database, if your file has the createdb commands in it, then you can run it from template1

Comment: psql template1 postgres -f testdbdump

Comment: or just do a pg_restore testdbdump

Comment: if i just to the pg_restore testdbdump and try to log in afterwards, the databsae is not there.

Comment: run pg_dump -C -U testuser testdb -F t> testdbdump

Comment: -C includes create database info

Comment: ok... I'll try that.  what version of the restore command do yu want me to use?

Comment: pg_restore testdbdump

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41229/discussion-between-dot-and-nathan-liddle)

Answer (score 1):

Look up the `--create` option of `pg_restore`.  It's made for this purpose.

Comment: I have been trying the -C option... like so: # pg_restore testdbdump -C -h 127.0.0.1.  It seems to show the contents of my tar file... and then I get my prompt back.  But when I sign into postgres, i don't have my database.  Does the userID I use to create / restore matter?